Is there a way to see the console output of a single JS file using VS Code?
I have a pretty simple function that I want to test but I'm not sure how to see the output. Do I need to create an HTML file and open it in a browser to see the result in the console? Or is there a way to see the console log directly in VS Code?
const myArray = [1,4,6,8,9,10,11,13];

findIndexOfNumber(myArray, 10);

function findIndexOfNumber(arr, target) {
    console.log(arr.indexOf(target))
    return arr.indexOf(target)
}

I wrote this up in a JS file. I understand I can just make an HTML file and link the two but I want to know if there is a quicker way to just see the results in VS Code from just the JS file alone.

You don't even need VSC for that. Just paste it into your browser's console

@j08691, Ah i see that works Thanks! that's way faster, this is exactly the asnwer I was looking for

Simply run the file in VSC (it will run it using Node). Or in a terminal (which can be the VSC one) using Node: node path/to/file.js

Yes you see in the output also.

